# Create function to create table Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to create table inside POSTGRESQL function but getting following error.

> ERROR:  no schema has been selected to create in CONTEXT:  SQL
>   statement "    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test.t_testing (
>       id serial PRIMARY KEY,
>       customerid int,
>       daterecorded date,
>       value double precision    )"

My function is as follows.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test.create_table_type1(t_name varchar(30))
  RETURNS VOID AS
$func$
BEGIN

EXECUTE format('
   CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS %I (
    id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    customerid int,
    daterecorded date,
    value double precision
   )', 'test.t_' || t_name);

END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test.create_table_type1(t_name varchar(30))
  RETURNS VOID AS
$func$
BEGIN

EXECUTE format(
    'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS %I.%I (
        id serial       PRIMARY KEY,
        customerid      int,
        daterecorded    date,
        value           double precision
    )',
   'test',
   ( 't_' || t_name )
);

END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

So sepparate 'schema' and 'table'.